# How do you know a socket client disconnected?

Tags: perl, sockets

I'm having a little trouble using sockets in a Perl server.

How can you know a (non-blocking) client just disconnected ?
In C, I'm used to doing

```
if (recv(sock, buff, size, flags) == 0) {
    printf("Client disconnected\n";
}
```

or the equivalent in python or other languages : `recv` returns -1 if no data is available, 0 if client exited, a positive number if data could be read.

But perl's `recv` doesn't work this way, and using `$data = <$sock>` does not seem to give any possibility to know.

Is there any (simple) possibility ?

Comment: Are you using any asynchronous framework?

Comment: Note.  When you say "recv returns -1 if no data is available".  That's not entirely correct.  recv will return -1 when there is no data available and set errno to either EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.  But there are other cases where recv could return -1 as well - mostly as a result of the TCP connection getting interrupted (e.g. remote peer crashed without shutting down his socket, losing internet, etc...). In other words, you shouldn't rely on "-1" being returned by recv.  Always check the corresponding errno to see if it's a recoverable error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a look at `perldoc perlio` and `perldoc IO::Socket`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use IO::Socket;
```

There is a lot of ways to compose with non-blocking IOs, from `PIPE` signal to `recv` you could use (depending on what you are doing):

```
return "Socket is closed" unless $sock->connected;
```

That is how I've controlled many sockets to serve them with `select`. When a socket is closed, I have to remove them from list (nothing else, as if disconnect, the socket doesn't exist anymore, so there is no need to close them):

```
unless (eval {$group{$grp}->{'socket'}->connected}) {
    delete $group{$grp}->{'socket'};
    return 0;
};
```

The `eval` prevents a bad try to a disconnected socket which will end your script with a *socket io error*.

Hope this helps!